# Is it possible to create group chat dialog/room from the server instead of client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chat, quickblox

I am using ruby on rails at server side. I want to use quickblox as chat solution. And my requirement is to create group chat room from the server side instead of client side(android, ios). I am able to register user from the backend, but the issue is I am getting the following error, while creating a chat dialog, from the server.

I am using this link for integrating the quickblox api:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Create_dialog

Error {"errors":{"base":["Forbidden. Need user."]}}.

Comment: I have answer the same query on stackoverflow
[Error {"errors":{"base":["Forbidden. Need user."]}}.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947701/trying-to-create-a-quickblox-group-chat-dialog-get-error-when-using-rest-api-to?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a dialog you need to be logged in

Use next request http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#API_User_Sign_In